# How to hide meta from search result only on pages?

Tags: posts, search, post-meta, author, date

I have different content on static pages and post in my WP site. On pages is not desirable to view meta in search result, but in my post is important.
Meta, I mean information about author, and date in search result.

I have created custom post-search.php. But i dont know, how to show meta information only for post in result.
No for showing meta i using this part of code:

```
        <div class="postmeta-primary">

        <span class="meta_date"><?php the_time($theme->get_option('dateformat')); ?></span>
       &nbsp; <span class="meta_author"><?php the_author(); ?></span>

            <?php if(comments_open( get_the_ID() ))  {
                ?> &nbsp; <span class="meta_comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'No comments', 'themater' ), __( '1 Comment', 'themater' ), __( '% Comments', 'themater' ) ); ?></span><?php
            }?> 

    </div>
```

I just thinking about some kind of "IF". For example If  its_post then execute code (which I post above)

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this inside the WordPress loop:

```
if (get_post_type() == 'post') {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found working solution. Maybye will be helpfull for someone.

```
 <div class="postmeta-primary">

    <?php if(get_post_type() == 'post'): {

     ?><span class="meta_date"><?php the_time($theme->get_option('dateformat')); ?></span>
       &nbsp; <span class="meta_author"><?php the_author(); ?></span><?php
            }?> 
    <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if(comments_open( get_the_ID() ))  {
                ?> &nbsp; <span class="meta_comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'No comments', 'themater' ), __( '1 Comment', 'themater' ), __( '% Comments', 'themater' ) ); ?></span><?php
            }?> 

    </div>
```